# Storing temporary data received through an API call

Tags: php, api, oauth

I am working on a web app which uses Google oAuth flow and Drive API to list user's Google Drive files. With the `access_type` set to online, my app doesn't receive a refresh token.

My question is, once I receive user's data, which is just meant to be shown so storing in DB is not an option, should I store that huge data object in a session variable or cookie?? So that when user refreshes the page, for a short amt of time, it would still be there and the user doesn't have to repeat the google consent screen step.

What would be the best way to deal with data that isn't meant to stored permanently??

Comment: Caching? Whether in client or server side depends on the needs.

Comment: Have you looked at HTML5 LocalStorage?